Cassandra/Scylla Counters; What's the most common approach to tracking the count for emoji reactions?
I am trying to design a posts table, where a user can react to the post with any emoji. I need to keep a count of each unique emoji that is used.
If I use a separate Counter table, for each post I receive, I have to make a query for the counts. So pulling 12 messages means 1 query for the messages, + 12 for the counts if I use a separate table.
Is there another more common approach to this? I can't bake the counter column directly into the posts table because the emoji/reaction's would be random.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This is a specific problem. How much more specific I can be? I need help designing a simple table.

I am not sure what you meant by "pulling 12 messages means 1 query for the messages, + 12 for the counts". If you can really read these 12 messages in one query, it means you have some sort of partition key or something that allows you to SELECT all 12 messages together. If that's the case, you can have the same partition key in the counter table as well.
If you want to use just one table, or using materialized views, you shouldn't be using "counters" and can instead use a regular integer column which you can increment using lightweight transactions (LWT). This will make the read very efficient (you just read the post record, and it includes the reaction counter in them) but the more infrequent reactions will be less efficient.
For a relatively few very popular posts that will receive a huge amount of interactions, these LWT transactions can be expensive and you can perhaps consider an alternative, perhaps even an additional counter column (i.e., have both an integer column and a counter on a separate table, and when the regular column reaches 1000, you will also read from the separate counter column, and increment it - not the regular column). However, arguably even for a very popular post it is read much more frequently than it is interacted with - imagine the post being likes a million times - but read 10 million times - so even LWT transactions might be fine as they are still the minority of the activity of the database.

Okay so by +12, I mean say the messages are in a table partitioned by a channel_id, similar to Discord and the clustering key is the timestamp so I can sort by recency.
When I query by the channel_id, I pull 12 messages. Since these 12 messages have reaction counts stored in a separate counter table that is partitioned by message_id, for each message, I need to make a request with the message_id for the counts from the counter table.
1 read request for 12 messages.
12 read requests per message via message_id
Re: your approach, aren't LWT costly/frowned upon since its 3 queries? R/W/R

I am still curious about this, because I'm not sure if its in good practice to do "batch reads". Another example, some messages might be a reply to another message, a parent. Would a person also have to store the parent message in that reply or would it make more sense to collect all messages with parent id's and do a batch read with those id's and merge the parent content into the main message?
